# $this->load->db(); initialize in class constructor?

Tags: codeigniter

I am putting this code in the constructor for a model class, based on teh tutorial for CI, it states that if you put it there, the database connection can be used globally within that class afterwards.  For some reason it's not working and the application crashes at that part of the code. My database configuration is fine since when i put it in the controller i'm able to get db info fine.

Comment: Please clarify and clean up your question.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this because it is not a real question, I assure you, this is a worthwhile question.

Comment: Just a note if none of the solutions work for you, when I modified my CI installation to allow for autocomplete in Eclipse my db started failing to load.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing that before or after the parent class's constructor?

```
public function __construct()
{
    // placing it here fails: $this has no `load` property yet.
    // $this->load->database(); <!-- NO WAY JOSÉ!
    parent::__construct();
    // placing it here should work as the parent class has added that property
    // during it's own constructor
    $this->load->database();
}
```

On the other hand, you could be even more explicit:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Doesn't matter where this goes:
    // grab the controller directly
    $CI =& get_instance(); // & is not strictly necessary, but still...
    // force the loader to load the database.
    $CI->load->database();
    // directly assign it.
    $this->db = $CI->db;
    // continue on your merry way
    parent::__construct();
}
```

I believe the explicit solution solved a number of problems in a PHP 4 project once, but it is technically overkill.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to initialize that . better configure it into 
`application - config - autoload.php` file like this

```
   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Answer (score 0):

The line of code to load the database object is:

```
$this->load->database();
```

The database object is then referenced with the name db like so:

```
$this->db->method_name();
```

As pointed out by the previous post, if you are going to use the database across multiple models, you should have the library autoloaded in your autoload.php config file.